# Tips to improve alignment in equation array

Tags: math-mode, arrays

```
\color{magenta}
$$\begin{array}{rrr|c|l} 
x & y & z & = &\text{Operation}\\\hline
1 & 1 & -2 & 7 & \\
3 & -1 & 1 & 2 & \text{II.}-3\cdot\text{I.} \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 8 & -\text{III.}-2\cdot\text{I.} \\\hline
1 & 1 & -2 & 7 & \\ 
& -4 & 7 & -19 & \\
0 & 1 & 9 & -6 & 4\cdot\text{III.}+\text{II.}\\\hline
1 & 1 & -2 & 7 & \\
0 & -4 & 7 & 19 & \\
0 & 0 & 43 & -43 & \\\hline\hline
\end{array}$$
```

[image]

How can I make the right a little bit more alligned?

Comment: I would probably right-align all columns.

Comment: What you mean with "How can I make the right a little bit more aligned"? BTW, Use of `$$` in LaTeX is deprecated ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht how?

Comment: To right-align all columns, just use `\begin{array}{rrr|r|r}` instead of `\begin{array}{rrr|c|l}`. Of course, this would align the first row as well. You could un-align single cells using something like `\multicolumn{1}{l}{<left-aligned>}`.

Comment: @Zarko nah that question doesn't work here. you know exactly what i mean

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks it worked

Comment: By the way: Zarko's question is totally fine in my opinion. Something is either aligned or it is not. So, the question about what you mean with "a bit more aligned" is indeed valid, since you did not state what exactly should be aligned.

Comment: @JasperHabicht where do i have to put the multi?

\multicolumn{1}{1}{<left-aligned>}\color{magenta}
$$\begin{array}{rrr|c|r} 
x & y & z & = &\text{Operation}\\\hline
1 & 1 & -2 & 7 & \\
3 & -1 & 1 & 2 & \text{II.}-3\cdot\text{I.} \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 8 & -\text{III.}-2\cdot\text{I.} \\\hline
1 & 1 & -2 & 7 & \\ 
& -4 & 7 & -19 & \\
0 & 1 & 9 & -6 & 4\cdot\text{III.}+\text{II.}\\\hline
1 & 1 & -2 & 7 & \\
0 & -4 & 7 & 19 & \\
0 & 0 & 43 & -43 & \\\hline\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: u did not state exactly where it should be put

Comment: See my answer below (or the one of egreg).

Comment: The multicolumn is supposed to be used on the word "Operation". In this spirit, you may also split the last column into two columns, such that the first and second terms of the sum are separated - this gives some alignment of this portion. Then you will really need the multicolumn such that the Heading "Operation" spans across two columns.

Answer (score 5):

First of all two recommendations:

1. never use `$$` in LaTeX, but `\[...\]` in this case
2. the color changing command should go behind `\[`

There's no real way to get “more alignment” with your style, where the row names have very different widths.

I suggest using a simpler symbol such as *R*<sub>3</sub> for denoting the third row, instead of III. that's hard to parse.

However, you may use the ← idea also with your naming scheme.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
\color{magenta}
\begin{array}{rrr|c|l}
x &  y &  z & = & \text{Operations} \\
\hline
1 &  1 & -2 & 7 & \\
3 & -1 &  1 & 2 & R_2 \gets R_2-3R_1 \\
2 &  3 &  5 & 8 & R_3 \gets -R_3-2R_1 \\
\hline
1 &  1 & -2 &   7 & \\
0 & -4 &  7 & -19 & \\
0 &  1 &  9 &  -6 & R_3 \gets 4R_3+R_2 \\
\hline
1 &  1 & -2 &   7 & \\
0 & -4 &  7 &  19 & \\
0 &  0 & 43 & -43 & \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
\color{magenta}
\begin{array}{rrr|c|rcl}
x &  y &  z & = & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\text{Operations}} \\
\hline
1 &  1 & -2 & 7 & \\
3 & -1 &  1 & 2 & \mathrm{II.}  &\gets& \mathrm{II.}-3\mathrm{I.} \\
2 &  3 &  5 & 8 & \mathrm{III.} &\gets& -\mathrm{III.}-2\mathrm{I.} \\
\hline
1 &  1 & -2 &   7 & \\
0 & -4 &  7 & -19 & \\
0 &  1 &  9 &  -6 & \mathrm{III.} &\gets& 4\mathrm{III.}+\mathrm{II.} \\
\hline
1 &  1 & -2 &   7 & \\
0 & -4 &  7 &  19 & \\
0 &  0 & 43 & -43 & \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd not use magenta, nor those vertical rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{rrrcl}
x &  y &  z & = & \text{Operations} \\
\midrule
1 &  1 & -2 & 7 & \\
3 & -1 &  1 & 2 & R_2 \gets R_2-3R_1 \\
2 &  3 &  5 & 8 & R_3 \gets -R_3-2R_1 \\
\midrule
1 &  1 & -2 &   7 & \\
0 & -4 &  7 & -19 & \\
0 &  1 &  9 &  -6 & R_3 \gets 4R_3+R_2 \\
\midrule
1 &  1 & -2 &   7 & \\
0 & -4 &  7 &  19 & \\
0 &  0 & 43 & -43 & \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or the method I'd prefer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1 &  1 & -2 & 7 \\
3 & -1 &  1 & 2 \\
2 &  3 &  5 & 8
\end{array}\right]
&\rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1 &  1 & -2 &   7 \\
0 & -4 &  7 & -19 \\
0 &  1 &  9 &  -6
\end{array}\right]
&& \begin{aligned}
   R_2 &\gets R_2-3R_1 \\
   R_3 &\gets -R_3-2R_1
   \end{aligned}
\\
&\rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1 &  1 & -2 &   7 \\
0 & -4 &  7 &  19 \\
0 &  0 & 43 & -43
\end{array}\right]
&& R_3 \gets 4R_3+R_2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to right-align all columns. I am unsure how you imagine the rightmost column to be aligned, but right-alignment is probably a good solution in this case.

To change the alignment of the columns, you need to change the column type from `l` or `c` to `r`. So, you should replace `\begin{array}{rrr|c|l}` by `\begin{array}{rrr|r|r}`.

This change of alignment will also affect the first row with the headers. In case you wish to have the cells in the first row of the table left-aligned, you can use the `\multicolumn` command, for example using `\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\text{Operation}}`.

One last note: The use of `$$...$$` is discouranged. Better use `\[...\]` instead. And the `\color` macro should probably go inside the math environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
\color{magenta}
\begin{array}{rrr|r|r} 
x & y & z & = &\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\text{Operation}}\\
\hline
1 & 1 & -2 & 7 & \\
3 & -1 & 1 & 2 & \text{II.}-3\cdot\text{I.} \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 8 & -\text{III.}-2\cdot\text{I.} \\
\hline
1 & 1 & -2 & 7 & \\ 
& -4 & 7 & -19 & \\
0 & 1 & 9 & -6 & 4\cdot\text{III.}+\text{II.}\\
\hline
1 & 1 & -2 & 7 & \\
0 & -4 & 7 & 19 & \\
0 & 0 & 43 & -43 & \\
\hline\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to make "Operation" center alligned?

Comment: Yes. Just replace `\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\text{Operation}}` by `\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\text{Operation}}`.

Comment: many thanks to you